# How to push in service without losing previous data?

Tags: angular

I have this:

```
    items = new ReplaySubject<Object>(1);

  setItems(obj){
    this.items.next(obj);
  }
  getItems(){
    return this.items.asObservable();
  }
```

in component i have this:

```
 this.sharedData.getItems().subscribe((data) => {
            return;
        })
```

Problem is whenever i use setItems i lose previous data. Any suggestion how can i avoid this? I want something as push in array to have previous data. Any suggestion how can i achive that?

Comment: Use an actual array?

Comment: How u mean? I will lose data when i go through components if i use array and not service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a public array within your service (@Injectable class). This would be a singleton so that data would be persistent throughout the app's lifecycle. From the service injected components, you can push/retrieve items to/from that array.